# Map 2 controller methods to the same endpoint with different query parameters

Tags: java, micronaut

I want to implement a REST API in Java with an "overloaded" endpoint which differs by the query parameters passed up.
I've tried this code in my controller class:

```
@Get("/query")
public MyResponse queryByDate(@QueryValue @Valid @Format("yyyy-MM-dd") Date date) {
    // Code to generate the response
    return retval;
}

@Get("/query")
public MyResponse queryByDateAndValue(@QueryValue @Valid @Format("yyyy-MM-dd") Date date, @QueryValue int value) {
    // Code to generate the response
    return retval;
}
```

This returns the following error:

```
More than 1 route matched the incoming request. The following routes matched /calendar/years/query: GET - /calendar/years/query, GET - /calendar/years/query
io.micronaut.web.router.exceptions.DuplicateRouteException: More than 1 route matched the incoming request. The following routes matched /calendar/years/query: GET - /calendar/years/query, GET - /calendar/years/query
```

Note that if I delete one of the methods, the remaining method works as expected.
How can I map an endpoint, with different query parameters, to 2 different methods in a controller? Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error because both endpoints have same path and it confuses compiler to map the APIs with corresponding paths. Passing query parameters does not mean the endpoint has different path. You can mere these 2 endpoints into one as:

```
@Get("/query")
public MyResponse queryByDateAndValue(@QueryValue @Valid @Format("yyyy-MM-dd") Date date,@DefaultValue("1")  @QueryValue int value) {
    // Code to generate the response
    return retval;
}
```

and set the default value of `value`. You can then separate your case accordingly.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Shame you can't do this the same way you can in Spring, but if Micronaut doesn't support it then I guess this is the best option. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Micronaut does not consider query parameters when matching a route, so separating the routes by query parameters will never work. I would advise doing what @Rahul suggested.